# Is there a recommended common pattern to memoize ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memoization

I'm working with some government data published via [Socrata's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrata) [SODA api](http://opendata.socrata.com/api/docs/).

This API provides a way to retrieve rows via a REST call. The API allows limited parameterization of the query - basically you can do a full text search, and nothing else. I cannot find a way to shape the data returned - for example only return certain columns of the data.

As a result, basically I can only get all rows and all columns of each data view.  This is ok, I guess, but I'd like to cache it - *memoize it* to use the underscore term.

Is there a pattern for memoization of ajax calls with jQuery?

---

**EDIT**:  To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, here's what I'm doing currently.

```
function onclick(event) {
    var $t = $(event.currentTarget);
    var itemId = $t.attr('data-itemid');
    var url = getRestUrl(itemId);
    if (typeof datacache[itemId] === "undefined") {
        $.ajax({
            url       : url,
            cache     : true,
            type      : "GET",
            dataType  : "json",
            error     : function(xhr,status,error) {
                raiseError(error);
            },
            success   : function(response, arg2, xhr) {
                datacache[itemId] = response;
                doSomethingWithTheData(url, itemId);
            }});
    }
    else {
        doSomethingWithTheData(url, itemId);
    }
}

// then, doSomethingWithTheData() simply references datacache[itemId]
```

This *seems* like it's faster though I haven't measured it.  What I really want to know is, *is there a common pattern that does something like this, that I can employ, so that everyone who reads the code will immediately see what I'm doing??*

Comment: Seems like it'd depend a **lot** on the nature of the data source.

Comment: Why so?  Suppose the data coming back is json. I want to minimize XHR usage, and even want to minimize XHR-with-cached-results.  The pattern ought to be pretty simple, and generic.

Comment: What I meant was that it depends on the "momoizability" of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do something like is done with autocomplete lookups (this is very much from memory, but you'll get the idea):

```
var searchCache = {}, searchXhr = null;

function Search(term) {

    if (term in searchCache) {
        return doSomethingWithTheData(searchCache[term]);
    }

    if (searchXhr != null) {
        searchXhr.abort();
    }

    searchXhr = $.ajax({
        url       : url,
        cache     : true,
        type      : "GET",
        dataType  : "json",
        error     : function(xhr, status, error) {
            raiseError(error);
        },
        success   : function(response, arg2, xhr) {
            searchCache[term] = response;
            if (xhr == searchXhr) {
                doSomethingWithTheData(response);
                searchXhr = null;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not necessarily the best expert for Javascript question, but I might be able to help you with your use of SODA.

If you're looking for more flexibility in your queries, and you can do an HTTP POST, you could look at using our query syntax to do a more targeted query: http://dev.socrata.com/querying-datasets. Our query syntax is fairly complex, but I can help you figure out how to structure your query if you hit any snags.

Unfortunately, since that'd require a POST, you'll need to break out of the XHR cross-domain lockbox by going through a proxy or something similar.

Also, FYI, we're working on a whole new syntax that'll allow you to specify queries as URL parameters, so you'll be able to perform simple requests such as `/resources/agencies?acronym=CIA` or `/resources/agencies?$where='budget > 10000000'`. It should be pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I will try that.  I was looking for just that documentation, but didn't find it.  Not sure why.  There will be no problem using POST. I'm using IIRF and ProxyPass to connect to the datasource.

Comment: ok, I tried that; it didn't work the way I expected. I'm not actually connecting to opendata.socrata.com.  I'm connecting to a govt agency. Is the query feature supported on all publicly accessible socrata endpoints? I do have some other questions. and comments, too, if you're interested. maybe better offline.

Answer (score 0):

You would only cache ajax requests that you know won't change, like the Facebook SDF for example.  It seems like in your example, you're requesting something UI related that might be inappropriate to cache?  Otherwise, you might try something like this:

var store = {};

```
/**
 * Memoized $.getScript
 *
 * Cache one script response per url
 * Reference, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg723713.aspx
 *
 * @example $.memoizedGetScript( url ).then( successCallback, errorCallback );
 * @param {String} url
 * @param {Function} callback (optional)
 * @returns {*}
 */
$.memoizedGetScript = function(url, callback) {
    var callback = callback || {};

    store.cachedScripts = {};

    if (!store.cachedScripts[url]) {
        store.cachedScripts[url] = $.Deferred(function(d) {
            $.getScript(url).then(
                d.resolve(),
                d.reject()
            );
        }).promise();
    }

    return store.cachedScripts[url].done(callback);
};
```